# Filter non-repeating values from a file in Solaris

Tags: unix, filter, filtering, solaris

I have a file in Solaris. The following is a sample from the file:

```
CELLO;998;CMGW4;20070926;1030;00000000;0000;15;/cpm_data;172.20.19.5;22;ON;true;UTC+06:00;Etc/GMT-6 
CELLO;999;CMGW1;20070920;1730;00000000;0000;15;/cpm_data;172.20.11.4;21;OFF;true;UTC+06:00;Etc/GMT-6
CELLO;999;CMGW3;20070629;1845;00000000;0000;15;/cpm_data;172.20.19.4;22;ON;true;UTC+06:00;Etc/GMT-6 
CELLO;999;CMGW4;20070926;1130;00000000;0000;15;/cpm_data;172.20.19.5;22;ON;true;UTC+06:00;Etc/GMT-6 
CELLO;99;CMGW5;20070930;1630;00000000;0000;15;/cpm_data;172.20.11.6;22;ON;true;UTC+06:00;Etc/GMT-6  
CELLO;9;CMGW4;20120330;1215;00000000;0000;15;/cpm_data;172.20.19.5;22;ON;true;UTC+06:00;Etc/GMT-6
```

I am interested in the 3rd column (separated by ;) i.e the filed starting with CMGW.
I want to get only the 3rd column unique values. Considering the sample above, the output that I want is:

```
CMGW1
CMGW3
CMGW4
CMGW5
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
awk -F\;  '{print $3}' data | sort -u
```

Where  `data` is the name of your data file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I tried your piece of code.I executed `awk -F \;  '{print $3}' mgwlist.txt | sort -u` but got `awk:syntax error near line 1` and `awk:bailing out near line1`. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Aaah for solaris you can't put the space between the `-F` and the `\;`.  Sorry I tested it on OSX.

Comment: Hey there, I've posted a new question which I think you can help me. Please have a look [Truncate trailing characters in Solaris](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25010893/2169224?sem=2)