# Truncate trailing characters in Solaris

Tags: unix, text, filter, extract, solaris

I have a text file in a Solaris workstation. Please see a sample of contents of the file below (The number of entries can vary):

```
CMSBC01                   TELNET_APG40
CMSBC01_1                 TELNET_APG40
CMSBC03                   TELNET_APG40
CMSBC03_1                 TELNET_APG40
GMSC1                     TELNET_APG40
GMSC2                     SSH_APG40
```

I am only interested about the 1st column entries. I want the output to be :

```
CMSBC01  
CMSBC01_1
CMSBC03  
CMSBC03_1
GMSC1    
GMSC2
```

I have tried

```
awk -F\;  '{print $1}' /home/els/axelist.txt
```

and also:

```
cat axelist.txt | sed 's/ *//'
```

But still not able to extract the 1st column.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: `awk` should work. Why do you specify `;` as the field delimiter, when it's just whitespace?

Comment: Your `sed` command just removes the spaces, it doesn't remove the column _after_ the spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk '{print $1}' axelist.txt
```

The default field separator in `awk` is any sequence of whitespace.

With sed it should be:

```
sed 's/ .*//' axelist.txt
```

You were missing the `.`, so it was just removing the spaces, not everything *after* the spaces.

Comment: Is there any way to re-populate the axelist.txt file with the output received from `awk '{print $1}' axelist.txt` thereby overwriting previous contents?

Comment: `sed` has the `-i` option to replace the file. `awk` has no similar option -- you have to write to a new file and then rename it.

Comment: Tried `sed -i 's/ .*//' axelist.txt` but got `Illegal option -- i`. I'm using solaris. Am I running the code correctly?

Comment: I don't have access to Solaris these days, you might need to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sed` to get modern options.

Comment: @Barmar `-i` is a GNU specific non POSIX option so `/usr/xpg4/bin/sed` won't help here.

Comment: @slyclam what version of Solaris are you using? It exists on my box, does your MAN page document it? 

@jlliagre it works here. in fact:

`$ md5sum /bin/sed /usr/xpg4/bin/sed /usr/gnu/bin/sed
582e637b31d1bd8311683004cdf867b8  /bin/sed
582e637b31d1bd8311683004cdf867b8  /usr/xpg4/bin/sed
cb53132c0ae0fb4c367848acedd3277c  /usr/gnu/bin/sed`

_OpenIndiana Development oi_151.1.7 X86, Assembled October 03 2012_